# knockout durandal this... not a funtion

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

I have this code:

```
define(['plugins/dialog', 'knockout', 'backend', 'durandal/app', 'datepicker', 'datepicker_ko'], function (dialog, ko, backend, app, datepicker, datepicker_ko) {
    var ApplicationForm = function(config) {
        this.config = ko.observableArray(config);
    };

    ApplicationForm.prototype.submit = function() {
        backend.setFormConfig(this.config()).then(function(response){
                dialog.close(this);
        });

    };

    ApplicationForm.show = function(config){
        return dialog.show(new ApplicationForm(config));
    };

    return ApplicationForm;
});
```

congig in the mainfile main.js:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        'text': '../lib/require/text',
        'durandal':'../lib/durandal/js',
        'plugins' : '../lib/durandal/js/plugins',
        'transitions' : '../lib/durandal/js/transitions',
        'knockout': '../lib/knockout/knockout-3.1.0',
        'validation_ko': '../lib/knockout/knockout-validation',
        'bootstrap': '../lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap',
        'jquery': '../lib/jquery/jquery-1.9.1',
        'underscore': '../lib/underscore/underscore-min',
        'datepicker': '../lib/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker',
        'datepicker_ko': '../lib/datepicker/datepicker_ko'
    },
    shim: {
        'bootstrap': {
            deps: ['jquery'],
            exports: 'jQuery'
       }
    }
});
```

And my Problem is, that I get the error:

```
TypeError: this.config is not a function
```

I do this many times in my project  ans with observables works it fine but not with observableArrays. What do I wrong?

Comment: Try defining var self = this; outside the ApplicationForm (under define) and in ApplicationForm use self.config. Does that work?

Comment: Unfortunately not :(

Comment: Where is config defined in the code you posted? I don't see where a config variable is made...

Comment: I have added the config to the question. It is in the mainfile of my durandal project

Answer (score -1):

```
define(['plugins/dialog',
    'knockout', 
    'backend', 
    'durandal/app', 
    'datepicker', 
    'datepicker_ko'], function (dialog, ko, backend, app, datepicker, datepicker_ko) {
var config = ko.observableArray([]);

var submit = function(){
   var request = config();
   backend.setFormConfig(request).then(function(response){
          dialog.close(viewmodel);
   });
}

var show = function(config){
    dialog.show(viewmodel, config);
}

var activate = function(config){
  config(config);
}

var viewmodel = 
{
  config: config,
  submit: submit,
  show: show,
  activate: activate
};

return viewmodel;});
```

Comment: As someone fairly new to Durandal, requirejs, et al., I find this "answer" severely lacking in explanation. (-1)